# How do I make link_to open external URLs in a new window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to convert a rails 2.3 site so that all external URLs open in a new window.  I could go though every call to `link_to` and add `:target => '_blank'`, but I'd like to do it in one step for all links, present and future.  Is there a way I can monkey patch link_to to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Please don't do this. Respect your users and leave it to them to decide how they would like links to open.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I think I'll respect my bosses and do as I'm told instead.

Comment: sometimes it's better to say no to our boss. I agree with John don't do this

Comment: This week on Stack Overflow: developer asks for help, other devs torpedo his career!

Comment: Simon, it is good to respect your boss, and do as you are told. However, when your boss ask you to do something that you disagree with, it is your responsibility and your job to say "no" to him/her. It is unprofessional not to question the decisions made by your employer, however, when you do say "no" you need to be able to show your employer that it is not a good choice. If you do not say "no", and help your boss out when wrong decisions is made, then who will? - If he/she is wrong this time, I don't want to say. It really depends on the context.

Comment: Ha.. ha... Yeah.. My mortgage is due, and my kids like to eat.. No I won't tab out :) @Jazz... that was so funny and concise.

Comment: Cort3z, the thing is Simon never said he disagrees with this, you're the ones who disagree with it. It's not his responsibility to say no because a bunch of people on stackoverflow disagree with his boss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I went with this, in an initialiser:

```
module ExternalLinksInNewTabs
  def new_tab_link_to *args, &block
    if block_given?
      options = args.first || {}
      html_options = args[1] || {}

      if options.is_a? String
        if ExternalLinksInNewTabs.is_external_link? @controller.request.host, options
          html_options[:target] = '_BLANK'
        end
      end

      same_tab_link_to options, html_options, &block
    else
      name = args.first
      options = args[1] || {}
      html_options = args[2] || {}

      if options.is_a? String
        if ExternalLinksInNewTabs.is_external_link? @controller.request.host, options
          html_options[:target] = '_BLANK'
        end
      end

      same_tab_link_to name, options, html_options
    end
  end

  def self.is_external_link? host, url
    host.sub! /^www\./, ''
    url =~ /^http/i && url !~ /^http:\/\/(www\.)?#{host}/i
  end
end

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module UrlHelper
      include ExternalLinksInNewTabs

      alias_method :same_tab_link_to, :link_to
      alias_method :link_to, :new_tab_link_to
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In Rails 4, `@controller` is not defined and also this lacks of https support. Here the changes https://gist.github.com/RoxasShadow/b5c59152183ff9ba0757/revisions. Thanks for the snippet btw.

Answer (score 17):

You should not have to change your server-side code for this view problem.

You should use Unobscursive javascript.
This example will only make external links showing up in a new window :

```
// jQuery
//
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    link_host = this.href.split("/")[2];
    document_host = document.location.href.split("/")[2];

    if (link_host != document_host) {
      window.open(this.href);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This caused problems for me with jquery links

Answer (score 3):

You just add an helper to add this options in your link_to

If you want add it on each link_to to can add on ApplicationHelper

```
def link_to(*args, &block)
  if block_given?
    args = [(args.first || {}), (args.second || {}).merge(:target => '_blank')]
  else
    args = [(args.first || {}), (args.second || {}), (args.third || {}).merge(:target => '_blank')]
  end
  super(args, block)
end
```

Or you can create your own link_to helper

```
def link_to_blank(*args, &block)
  if block_given?
    args = [(args.first || {}), (args.second || {}).merge(:target => '_blank')]
  else
    args = [(args.first || {}), (args.second || {}), (args.third || {}).merge(:target => '_blank')]
  end
  link_to(args, block)
end
```

Comment: Won't this also change internal links?  Perhaps the Simon should just use some javascript to target the external links?

Comment: change all link generate by link_to helper. You can't do more.

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3.2+, it has been added as an option, just add

```
= link_to 'facebook', 'http://www.facebook.com/fb-page', target: '_blank'
```

and it'll open the link in a new tab.

Comment: The problem isn't how to make one link open in a new window; it's how to make all external links open in a new window.